# Desk Pencil Sharpener - what's the purpose of the feeding arm?

Tags: pencils, tool-usage

Pretty minor - but it puzzles me. All desk pencil sharpeners I've encountered have a spring triggered "feeding arm" (see image where the arm is extended).

[image: Extended pencil sharpener]

What's its purpose? I can sharpen a pencil without extending it, and after extending, why do I need the spring mechanism? It never triggers while there's a pencil inside.

Comment: "It never triggers while there's a pencil inside." then it's not working properly.

Comment: The arm is supposed to push the pencil towards the knife so you don't have to apply pressure manually and risk pushing too hard.

Comment: And also to keep the pencil properly aligned so you don’t sharpen it at an odd angle.

Comment: Keeping the pencil straight obviously, but I didn't even know such a thing existed :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In retrospect, I don't know how I missed it, but here are the details for anyone else wondering:

1. Pulling the feeding arm extends the spring. When the arm is pulled all the way back, it's locked.
2. At this point, rotating the sharpener crank (without a pencil) will release the lock, and cause the arm to spring back all the way in.
3. But instead we keep the arm locked, and secure a pencil inside. When we rotate the crank, the arm (which now 'carries' the pencil with it) doesn't spring all the way in because the pencil end hits the blade - which is laid out diagonally (thus creating the desired cone shape when rotating). The spring power is used to push the pencil towards the diagonal blade while it's rotating.
4. A secondary goal of the arm is to keep longer pencils leveled to create a symmetric sharpening.

(Thanks @wolff & @Janus!).

Comment: Have you tried out what happens if you keep turning the handle? If you did, you could observe that the entire structure in question is to **keep pulling the pencil inwards** as the sharpening process progresses.